# Restful URL design for register

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have Users collection which is accessible in '/users'. It has implemented with CRUD. My question is, for registering a new user, do I really need to create URL '/register'? Basically it violates Restful concept (register is a verb) but I tempt to since I need to do something else.

Comment: What does 'register' mean? Must a User exist for him to register? Is he created when registering?

Comment: Yes, new user will be added to users collection upon registering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
POST /users
```

with a User representation in the body to register a user.

In general, a `POST` to a collection resource is used to create a new resource in the collection.

Comment: But, in registering I do some operations such as checking phone verification. Should I do this in POST /users?

Comment: Yes. If the phone does not validate, return `400 Bad Request` to indicate the the passed user data can not be accepted. Remember, REST is not CRUD.